# Subscribing to values from another viewmodel in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to split my view models into multiple reuseable view models.
I have one view model which contains several dropdowns and one button.

```
    var TopView = function () {
       self.DropDownA = ko.observableArray();
       self.selectedDDA = ko.observable();
       self.DropDownB = ko.observableArray();
       self.selectedDDB = ko.observable();

       $.getJSON("someAPIurl", function (result) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, self);
        });  //this builds dropdownA

        $self.selectedDDA.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            $.getJSON("anotherAPI"+newValue, function (result) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, self);

            });
        };  // this builds dropdownB
        $self.buttonClicked = function() {
            alert("I clicked!");
        }
}
```

My main viewmodel looks like this:

```
var MainView = function () {
   var self = this;
   var topView = ko.observable({ TopView: new TopView() });

   // How do i get the selected values from topView once the user clicks the button???
}
```

How do I subscribe to DropDownA and DropDownB selected values from my mainview???
Please help!  Thank you!

Comment: You realize that you are using `self` in the `TopView` constructor without assigning it to `this` beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to make the `TopView` itself observable as long as you don't want to exchange it completeley. You just can create it as a property of `MainView` and access it simply like that in your bindings:

```
<button data-bind="click:topView.buttonClicked">click me, I&#39;m a button!</button>
```

**TopView** stays as it is (after you fixed your using of `self` and `$self` without defining them)

**MainView** would look like that:

```
var MainView = function () {
   var self = this;
   self.topView = new TopView();
}
```

**[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VGbD2/1/)**